# Is there a "result server" that store performance test result, with good analysis tool?

Tags: performance, performance-testing

I need a "result server" that can store my raw test data (server cpu, memory usage, etc), create report template (e.g. user number vs response time), generate live-reports base on templates, and perform complicated analysis (such as 70/80/90 percentile charts, data distribution comparison between test, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Microsoft platform, try using Visual Studio load testing functionality. It uses SQL Server for storing test results and will do all the kinds of analysis for you.

Answer (score 0):

If money's no object, HP as a tool called [Performance Center](https://h10078.www1.hp.com/cda/hpms/display/main/hpms_content.jsp?zn=bto&cp=1-11-126-17%5E1582_4000_100__), which is a webified version of Mercury LoadRunner (HP bough Mercury a while back; Performance Center was developed my Mercury, not HP) along with some rudimentary test management.

If you need to take it further, [HP Quality Center](https://h10078.www1.hp.com/cda/hpms/display/main/hpms_content.jsp?zn=bto&cp=1-11-127-24_4000_100__) (formerly Mercury Test Directory) provides additional capabilities.